# First line of input from file being read in endless loop, don't know how to move to next line

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the program to read lines of 3 numbers from a text file, then order them in ascending order, until it can't read anymore and then stops the program. Then I want it to tell me how many lines of code were read. However, whenever I try to run the program, it only keeps outputting the info from first line of numbers endlessly and doesn't move onto the others. Here's my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project4 {
public static void main (String[] args)
throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner name= new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Project #4");

    name = new Scanner(new File("data4.txt"));

    int a = name.nextInt();
    int b = name.nextInt();
    int c = name.nextInt();

  do {
     System.out.println("Original order of integers: "+a+" "+b+" "+c);

     if (a>=b && a>c) {
        if (b>c){
        System.out.println("The sorted integers are: " +c+" "+b+" "+a);}
        else{
        System.out.println("The sorted integers are: "+b+" "+c+" "+a);}
     }
     else if (b>=a && b>c){
        if (a<c){
        System.out.println("The sorted integers are: "+a+" "+c+" "+b);}
        else{
        System.out.println("The sorted integers are: "+c+" "+a+" "+b);}
     }
     else {
        if (b<a){
        System.out.println("The sorted integers are: "+b+" "+a+" "+c);}
        else{
        System.out.println("The sorted integers are: "+a+" "+b+" "+c);}
     }
 }while(name.hasNext());
 }
 }
```

I haven't added the part where it tells me all the loops that happened before it stopped, but I don't know how to do that either. Anyone know why it's only reading the first line of numbers over and over again?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @CoolGuy76 - I ran your program. Input file: 12345
33555
23333 and output displayed as I think you wanted? Project #4
Original order of integers: 12345 33555 23333
The sorted integers are: 12345 23333 33555

Comment: So therefore, I imagine there's something wrong in data4.txt

Answer (score 0):

This answer was 1 google away..just read the inputs from the file. Your program is not actually sorting the file at all, you are just displaying the " sort "

Book's solution:

```
public class Exercise03_08 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    // Enter three numbers
    System.out.print("Enter three integers: ");
    int number1 = input.nextInt();
    int number2 = input.nextInt();
    int number3 = input.nextInt();

    if (number1 > number2) {
      int temp = number1;
      number1 = number2;
      number2 = temp;
    }

    if (number2 > number3) {
      int temp = number2;
      number2 = number3;
      number3 = temp;
    }

    if (number1 > number2) {
      int temp = number1;
      number1 = number2;
      number2 = temp;
    }

    System.out.println("The sorted numbers are "
      + number1 + " " + number2 + " " + number3);
  }
}
```